# Unity Project - duplicate files

Tags: unity-game-engine

Recently I have been having a lot of issues with my unity project, specifically it seems like a lot of my files and directories are being duplicated.

This is a screenshot of what my directory and file hierarchy looks like:
[image: Finder on mac, showing some duplicate directories]

I don't know what is causing this, but I suspect it is involved in a lot of build issues I have been having lately. What I can think of is that I have been using the package "AI Planner" which is in an early preview stage (and has been massively problematic for me, although I am hoping this issue is responsible for that and not vice versa), as well as adding the "GitHub For Unity" plugin.

If you have any suggestions as to what might be causing this, I would be very grateful. Do let me know if there is additional information I can provide that might help.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you using _Git Submodules_ and _symbolic links?_ https://stackoverflow.com/a/47751345/585968  If so the link should start somewhere in the Plugins folder and end in the _specific subfolder (generally a child or two beneath the externals **Assets** folder) of the external repo you wish to use_, not the entire repo.

Comment: I don't think so, cause I don't know what either of those are. I'm not really doing anything special with the Git plugin, I just downloaded it according to the instructions and I'm using it like you would normally use git - pushing, pulling, committing etc. Currently I'm just keeping the entire unity project in a git repo, starting from the root of the project. Is this something I should not be doing?